# InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: cudaGetErrorString symbol not found

Tags: python, gpu, cuda

I run this code:

```
tf.test.is_gpu_available( cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None )
```

I get the following error:

> 2019-10-25 18:25:20.855191: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>   2019-10-25 18:25:20.879831: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44]
>   Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll 2019-10-25
>   18:25:21.461924: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0
>   with properties: name: GeForce MX130 major: 5 minor: 0
>   memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.189 pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 2019-10-25
>   18:25:21.470775: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25]
>   GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check. 2019-10-25
>   18:25:21.503654: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible
>   gpu devices: 0
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 tf.test.is_gpu_available( cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None )
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\deep_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\test_util.py
>   in is_gpu_available(cuda_only, min_cuda_compute_capability)    1430
>   1431   try:
>   -> 1432     for local_device in device_lib.list_local_devices():    1433       if local_device.device_type == "GPU":    1434         if
>   (min_cuda_compute_capability is None or
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\deep_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\device_lib.py
>   in list_local_devices(session_config)
>        39   return [
>        40       _convert(s)
>   ---> 41       for s in pywrap_tensorflow.list_devices(session_config=session_config)
>        42   ]
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\deep_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py
>   in list_devices(session_config)    2247     return
>   ListDevicesWithSessionConfig(session_config.SerializeToString())
>   2248   else:
>   -> 2249     return ListDevices()    2250    2251
>
> InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: cudaGetErrorString
>   symbol not found.

After crearing the following venv:

```
conda create -n Deep_learning_env python=3.6

pip install -U numpy matplotlib pandas ipython
git clone https://github.com/scipy.git scipy
pip install https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/CPU-Only/cntk-2.7.post1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
pip install https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/GPU/cntk_gpu-2.7.post1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
pip install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-gpu
pip install gensim
pip install keras
pip install  --upgrade --no-deps cntk
pip install --upgrade --no-deps cntk-gpu

conda install theano pygpu
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit
conda install -c anaconda cudnn

conda list cudnn
# Name   Version  Build      Channel
cudnn    7.6.0    cuda10.1_0    anaconda
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:12:52_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
python --version

Python 3.6.7
which nvcc
/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1/bin/nvcc
```

NVIDIA GeForce MX130

more info:
cntk                 2.7
cntk-gpu             2.7
tensorflow           2.0.0
tensorflow-estimator 2.0.1
tensorflow-gpu       2.0.0
ipython              7.8.0

also when I import tensorflow I get the following warning:

> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could
>   not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll
>   not found

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout this:
[Github tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33026#issuecomment-549847442)
Currently Cuda 10.1 is compatible with TF

Comment: On superuser, we add links only as reference, you should always provide at least a short explanation.

Comment: i think my GPU NVIDIA GeForce MX130  does not support any tensor flow coding that why it did not work because i tried it with cuda 9 and the above is with cuda 10.1 correct me if i am wrong ... this is because i checked the website for the gpu and they did not list it with the supported once !!